# Warehouse_Load_History -> Avg_Running column description is wrong?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the Snowflake.Account_Usage.Warehouse_Load_History view there is a column named **Avg_Running**. According to the documentation it says this field is the "Average number of queries executed". I don't see how this can be correct. I think it should be average execution time of queries? Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, the view is about WAREHOUSE and not about queries. The column is basically stating the AVG_RUNNING_QUERIES within a specified date range.

Query load is calculated by dividing the execution time (in seconds) of all queries in an interval by the total time (in seconds) for the interval.

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-load-monitoring.html#how-query-load-is-calculated

You may also be interested in looking at QUERY_HISTORY - which contains the query and warehouse details together.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html#query-history-view

Related warehouse view:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/warehouse_metering_history.html#warehouse-metering-history

Comment: Thank you @fkayani. I was not asking this question to learn the average running time of queries. I know how to determine that. My question is this. What does a value of .024 for AVG_RUNNING mean? I'd like to know what the numerator and denominator of this calculated value is.

Comment: updated my above answer as well. 

Query load is calculated by dividing the execution time (in seconds) of all queries in an interval by the total time (in seconds) for the interval.

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-load-monitoring.html#how-query-load-is-calculated

Comment: I'm not convinced this is correct. However, If it is correct then the documentation on what AVG_RUNNING means is incorrect. Which is the point of my original question. The documentation says "Average number of queries executed". The documentation you pointed me to says, "Execution time (in seconds) of all queries in an interval by the total time (in seconds)". This is not the same thing and I'm not convinced this is referring to the AVG_RUNNING field in the view.

Comment: IF you scroll down to the link, The chart shows that, during the five-minute interval, the load from running queries was .92 and queued queries (due to warehouse overload) was .08. The table below illustrates how these values were calculated based on the 5 queries that contributed to the warehouse load during the interval.